# Customising MacOS Bundle's Info.plist file with CMake

Tags: macos, cmake, nsbundle

I'm using CMake generate build files for a cross platform game and want to specify custom `NSMainNibFile` and `NSPrincipalClass` values in certain bundle's Info.plist file

Here's the relevant portion of my Info.plist.in template:

```
<key>NSMainNibFile</key>
<string>${MAIN_NIBFILE}</string>
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>${PRINCIPAL_CLASS}</string>
```

What I'm doing in my CMakeLists.txt is:

```
set_target_properties(GLWindow PROPERTIES
  MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME "OpenGL Test"
  MAIN_NIBFILE "MainMenu"
  PRINCIPAL_CLASS "NSApplication")
  MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/Info.plist.in)`
```

If I get the `MAIN_NIBFILE` property for the target, it returns MainMenu as expected, but the actual generated Info.plist is empty.

BUT...

If I globally set these variables, it works fine.

```
# I would prefer to set these at target scope, 
# but it doesn't bloody work!
set(MAIN_NIBFILE "MainMenu")
set(PRINCIPAL_CLASS "NSApplication")
```

Am I missing something here or is this a limitation of CMake or how it handles macOS bundles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST.html), you will see that it only supports setting a limited number of properties that affect the Info.plist template (`MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME`, etc). None of these are for the `NSMainNibFile` or `NSPrincipalClass` keys. However, in that documentation it gives a hint at the functionality of the template:

> its Info.plist file is created by configuring a template

What is actually happening, is that the module is calling [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/configure_file.html) on the .plist.in file. This is why setting variables at the global scope works, but setting them at the property level does not.

So, the answer is that you must set those as variables, not as target properties. If you are worried about scope of these, you can [`unset`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/unset.html) the variables immediately after use, and, it should be noted that variables only are not visible to their parent scopes, unless they are specifically set as such.

Comment: That sheds some light on it. I can't believe I didn't pick up on the bit about configuring the template (using configure_file) under the hood.

I can work around it anyway, I only need to specify XIB files and NSApplication subclasses in a plist for some tools.

Comment: Can some1 write a simple example or something? I've read it 15x I understand 0. :/ I'm trying to pass my plist to cmake & set variables on it with icon/etc.